# UnicodeEncodeError persisting in Python when I print a string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, pgmpy

I am using pgmpy for Bayesian Networks and am having problem when executing the following code.

```
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel
from pgmpy.factors.discrete import TabularCPD

model = BayesianModel([('D', 'G'), ('I', 'G'), ('G', 'L'), ('I', 'S')])

cpd_d = TabularCPD(variable='D', variable_card=2, values=[[0.6, 0.4]])
cpd_i = TabularCPD(variable='I', variable_card=2, values=[[0.7, 0.3]])


cpd_g = TabularCPD(variable='G', variable_card=3,
                   values=[[0.3, 0.05, 0.9,  0.5],
                           [0.4, 0.25, 0.08, 0.3],
                           [0.3, 0.7,  0.02, 0.2]],
                  evidence=['I', 'D'],
                  evidence_card=[2, 2])

cpd_l = TabularCPD(variable='L', variable_card=2,
                   values=[[0.1, 0.4, 0.99],
                           [0.9, 0.6, 0.01]],
                   evidence=['G'],
                   evidence_card=[3])

cpd_s = TabularCPD(variable='S', variable_card=2,
                   values=[[0.95, 0.2],
                           [0.05, 0.8]],
                   evidence=['I'],
                   evidence_card=[2])

model.add_cpds(cpd_d, cpd_i, cpd_g, cpd_l, cpd_s)


print(model.get_cpds('G'))
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-32: ordinal not in range(256)`

It would be great if someone could guide me out of this problem. Thank you so much for your time and cooperation.

Comment: Change your file path?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is this python 2?

Comment: Nope, Python 3.5.2.